# Non-singular matrix, determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I should find the values x for which the matrix is non-singular.

[image: Given matrix is]

I already know that the matrix is singular when *det(A)* is *0*. So basically the matrix will be non-singular when the determinant is something else than 0. I know how to find a determinant but I guess this should be solved "other way around"?

It's a homework so hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Reduce it to [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) and check when the leading term is $0$.

Comment: You can calculate $\det A$ outright.  But you can do row operations to $A$ to perhaps make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Calculate the determinant of this matrix. You get an expression that depends on $x$. When is this expression zero?

Comment: OH! Now I get the quadratic equation!
So does it mean that the solution of quadratic equation is the solution for x as well?

Comment: Yes, the determinant is zero if, and only if, the quadratic equation you get is zero. Therefore the matrix is singular if $x$ is a solution to that equation and non-singular otherwise.